# Prevent Cell Deletion

Tags: notebooks, cells

How might I be able to prevent a `Cell` form being deleted when you press the Delete key?

Maybe there is a way to display some type of `Dialog` when you attempt to delete(or cut) a cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is [`Deletable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Deletable.html):

> Deletable
>   is an option for Cell which specifies whether the cell can be deleted interactively using the front end.

You can set it either programmatically as shown in the documentation linked above, or with the **Option Inspector** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on Windows).

[image]

Comment: Ideally I am just looking for a way to double check that the user wants to `Delete` the cell, and not necessarily prevent it entirely.  I see tried and `DeleteWithWarning` but it didn't seem to work, might you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Liam I don't know of an option for that, but I'll think about it.